# Join two tables in codeiginter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I want to fetch data from two tables and then apply order by desc on my result set. I want to know the syntax of query in codeiginter. I want to match my story_id from the story_ratings table to the id of stories table and then order them according to top rated Here is my query:

```
$this->db->select('story_ratings.*,stories.*');
$this->db->from(' story_ratings');
$this->db->join('stories', 'story_ratings.story_id = stories.id', 'left'); 
$this->db->order_by('story_ratings.avg_rate','desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: See documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: what is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: I'm not getting result set, it says database error

Comment: @WWW Please add the error message to your question

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query()` to get last executed query. now you can see the error in query

Answer (score 3):

most smartest way to use all from 1 function you can put this in helper and pass your params from controller as per requirement.

```
function GetAllRecord($table_name='',$condition=array(),$join_table='',$table_id='',$join_id='',$is_single=false){
    $ci = & get_instance();
    #$ci->db->select('first_name,last_name');
    if($condition && count($condition))
        $ci->db->where($condition);
    $ci->db->from($table_name);
    if($join_table)
        $ci->db->join($join_table,"$table_name.$table_id = $join_table.$join_id");
    $res = $ci->db->get();
    if($is_single)
        return $res->row_array();
    else
        return $res->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code i think this will work

```
$this->db->select('a.*,b.*');
$this->db->join('stories b', 'a.story_id = b.id', 'left'); 
$this->db->order_by('a.avg_rate','desc');
$query = $this->db->get('story_ratings a');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  $query=$this->db->select('t1.*, t2.*')
 ->from('story_ratings as t1')   
 ->join('stories as t2', 't1.story_id = t2.id','left')
 ->order_by('t1.avg_rate','desc');   
 ->get();
```